# How to set max date in Datepicker Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I tried like as:

**JS code:**

```
 var today = new Date();
 var dd = today.getDate();
 var mm = today.getMonth()+6;
 var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

 $scope.maxDate = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
```

**HTML code:**

```
<input type="text" ng-click="open($event)" min-date="minDate" max-mode="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dtModel"/>
```

Comment: So, if the current date is 2015-11-28, the max date would be 2015-16-28?

Comment: what version of angular are you using?

Comment: You have a typo I think, it has to be "max-date", not "max-mode"?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, should work :

```
var today = new Date();

$scope.maxDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.setMonth()+6, today.getDate());
```

**EDIT**
Sorry, my bad :

```
var today = new Date();
  today.setMonth(today.getMonth()+6);


  $scope.maxDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth() , today.getDate());
```

I tested it on plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/Qb9N0OjhHWIH9ChtbF1J?p=preview

Comment: So, with this solution I can slide calendar to any year and select it

Answer (score 0):

Change your `max-mode` to `max-date` as suggested by @ThomasWeglinski above.

And then change your 6 months from now calculation to this:

```
var sixMonthsFromNow = today.setMonth(today.getMonth()+6);
var dd = sixMonthsFromNow.getDate();
var mm = sixMonthsFromNow.getMonth();
var yyyy = sixMonthsFromNow.getFullYear();
$scope.maxDate = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
```

Comment: The OP isn't using a raw date inut fiels, but an angular-ui datepicker: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker