# unable to add min date and max date validation in angular ui-bootstrap datepicker when using ui-bootstrap version 1.3.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, date

I am trying to add validation in my datepicker so that the user can not choose any date 30 days prior to current date and also can not choose any date 30 days in future, I am using below code for date picker-

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : memberForm.dateOfBirth.$invalid && (memberForm.dateOfBirth.$touched || memberForm.$submitted) }">
  <label for="Date of Birth" class="" ng-hide="memberForm.dateOfBirth.$invalid && (memberForm.dateOfBirth.$touched || memberForm.$submitted)">Date of Birth(dd/mm/yyyy)*</label>
  <label class="error_message_text" ng-show="memberForm.dateOfBirth.$invalid && (memberForm.dateOfBirth.$touched || memberForm.$submitted)"> Date of birth is required </label>
  <p class="input-group" style="width:270px;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dateOfBirth" uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

and I am using below scripts -

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>  
<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I have created a plunker here -
https://plnkr.co/edit/RmDyhjKpEJvTMjNRp5LE?p=preview

Can any one tell me how can I achieve this validation in my code?

Comment: You can just add `min-date="minDate"` and `max-date="maxDate"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set max date in Datepicker Angular JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687388/how-to-set-max-date-in-datepicker-angular-js)

Comment: Just set min date as current date and max date as .addDays(30).

Comment: @ Matheno @ Abhay I tried but it is not working, I have updated my plunker -https://plnkr.co/edit/RmDyhjKpEJvTMjNRp5LE?p=preview

Comment: @Matheno  Can u correct my plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
$scope.minDate = date.setDate((new Date()).getDate() - 30);
```

When you call date.setDate(..) it doesnot return the date object, so do this

```
$scope.toggleMin = function() {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate((new Date()).getDate() - 30);
    $scope.minDate = date;
  };
  $scope.toggleMin();


var date1 = new Date();
date1.setDate((new Date()).getDate() + 30);
$scope.dateOptions.maxDate = date1;
```

Little correction- (added .dateOptions while assigning min date and max date)

```
 $scope.toggleMin = function() {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setDate((new Date()).getDate() - 30);
        $scope.minDate = date;
      };
      $scope.toggleMin();

    //  Add this for maxDate, no code was there in plunker
    var date1 = new Date();
    date1.setDate((new Date()).getDate() + 30);
    $scope.dateOptions.maxDate = date1;
```

Answer Plunker-
https://plnkr.co/edit/RmDyhjKpEJvTMjNRp5LE?p=preview

Comment: I updated my plunker, still its not working, can u check my plunker and tell where I am missing? @Aman

Comment: could you be specific about the problem you are facing or update your question with the error message you are getting.

Comment: My issue is that  in my code I am unable to set min date to 30 days before and max date to 30 days in future

Comment: I added .dateOptions while assigning min date and max date values. and have updated my plunker- https://plnkr.co/edit/RmDyhjKpEJvTMjNRp5LE?p=preview it is working now Thanks @Aman

Answer (score 1):

you can use this for validation

```
var today = new Date()
var priorDate = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-30)
```

Comment: I tried with this , but its not working, I have updated my plunker, Can u check that and correct?